# Feature branch with or without fast-forward merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow, fast-forward

I'm using git for a long time now. But I've never used it in a collaborative way. I'm currently setting up a new project and planning a lot of things, among others: how to git?

Okay so I've started reading a bit and it was a simple decision to say: Fine, we'll use a feature branch workflow. That's awesome.

Next question: Merge or PR? Merge!
Fine.

Last question: **FF or non-FF?**
Does it even make sense to merge FF in a feature branch workflow? It just feels like the whole feature branch story is waste when merging FF.
Are there any drawbacks using non-FF that I've not considered?

---

When reading a "flat" (like `git log --oneline`) git log I think it's not a big deal having those merge commits. But when using some more fancy `git log --format ...` it can be totally helpful when a log looks like this. At least in my opinion.

```
*   e3f667e (HEAD, origin/master, master) Merge branch 'issue#1702'
|\
| * ec359fe (origin/issue#1702, issue#1702) 1702: two
| * 45a63b3 1702: two
* |   97bbec7 Merge branch 'issue#1701'
|\ \
| |/
|/|
| * f959cc9 (origin/issue#1701, issue#1701) 1701: two
| * 9217d3c 1701: one
|/
*   6c934ea Merge branch 'issue#1606'
|\
| * 365eac5 (origin/issue#1606, issue#1606) 1606: two
| * 95df1c9 1606: two
| * ad79b01 1606: one
|/
*   02dbcea Merge pull request #1 from babbelnedd/issue#1605
|\
| * d24d200 (origin/issue#1605, issue#1605) 1605: two
| * 7ef0a8e 1605: two
| * 5aac64d 1605: one
|/
* 585d8b9 Initial commit
```

Answer (score 8):

You are absolutely correct that it makes no sense to use feature branches while at the same time doing FF merges.

The "Gitflow way" is to *not* use FF when merging in topic branches:

> The --no-ff flag causes the merge to always create a new commit object, even if the merge could be performed with a fast-forward. This avoids losing information about the historical existence of a feature branch and groups together all commits that together added the feature.

([Source](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/))

Answer (score -1):

Looks like [Gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) headliners meant to use fast-forward merge.

Citation from [Jeff Kreeftmeijer's blog](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/) about the [Git-Flow tool](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). Note the "fast-forward" message.

> As the output already explains, you're now on a new branch you can use to work on your feature. Use git like you normally would, and finish the feature using feature finish when it's done:

```
$ git flow feature finish authentication
Switched to branch 'develop'
Updating 9060376..00bafe4
Fast-forward
 authentication.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 authentication.txt
Deleted branch feature/authentication (was 00bafe4).

Summary of actions:
- The feature branch 'feature/authentication' was merged into 'develop'
- Feature branch 'feature/authentication' has been removed
- You are now on branch 'develop'
```